# Is there a name for the $n=50$ quantiles?

Tags: terminology, quantiles

For $n = 5, 10, 20, 100$ we have quintiles, deciles, vigintiles, and percentiles. Is there a name for $n = 50$?

A candidate would be **quinquagintiles**, but I can't find that having being used.

Comment: Note that $n$ here does not mean sample size, but the number of intervals into which a distribution is divided.There are $4$ quintiles (point values) dividing a distribution into $5$ parts with (notionally) equal frequencies of values in each. On the question: I have never seen a specific term for this set in statistical discussions.. You are talking about about every other percentile.

Answer (score 2):

Why do you need a specific term? Can't you just describe it with words and numbers? I have never seen a term for this, and hope never to see one, it is not needed.

Your term [vigintile](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/vigintile) seem to exist, but I have never seen it "in the wild".

Comment: Indeed, if there is a word for it, most people won't know it, making it a poor choice to communicate anything useful. If a paper was talking about something in the 49th "50-quantile" (whatever the term would be), I'd shake my head at the fact that they were too pretentious to just call it the 98th percentile.

Comment: Although it's hard to prove a term does not exist, the [crowd-sourced Wiktionary entry about quantile names](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/vigintile) has nothing between "vigintile" and "centile", lending support to this negative answer. Moreover, if there were a term, most likely it would be modeled on the Latin ordinals and be called a "quinquagintile" (as in the Q), but this term gets only tentative search hits. *E.g.*, "If there are 50 bins, each bin should be termed a 'quinquagintile', according to our Latin dictionary."  K. Anderson and C. Brooks (2005). The Extremes of the P/E Effect.

Comment: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/235330/iles-terminology-for-the-top-half-a-percent  is the fullest list I know and includes "vigintile". Knowing some Latin or Greek doesn't necessarily make you pretentious, but I share the view that we don't need different terms just for different subsets of quantiles. I must add "hexadecile" but it appears predated by "suboctile".