# Is there a word for percentages, like "median" is for 50%?

Tags: terminology

Wikipedia article [Median](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Median) says:

> In statistics and probability theory, the median is the value separating the higher half from the lower half of a data sample, a population or a probability distribution.

Which can be rephrased as:

> In statistics and probability theory, the median is the value separating the higher 50% from the lower 50% of a data sample, a population or a probability distribution.

Is there a term for: "a value separating the higher (100−N)% from the lower N% of a data sample, a population or a probability distribution" ?

Edit:

The question ["-iles" terminology for the top half a percent](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/235330/273544) *itself* answers my question because it happens to contain the word I was looking for. But technically it is not a duplicate.

Comment: You also get minimum and maximum.

Comment: https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/tertile#Coordinate_terms

Comment: When you're talking about the percentiles that serve as thresholds to split the distribution into $n$ equally sized groups, there are special names. For $n=2$, it's the median; for $n=3$ they are called tertiles; for $n=4$ they are called quartiles, and so on.

Comment: The thread suggested as duplicate is more general than its title implies, with several detailed comments on various words here.

Answer (score 2):

Median is a second quartile (value that splits the data into two halves), a kind of [quantile](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantile), or 50-th [percentile](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percentile) (50% of the values are below this value), those are the terms you are looking for.

Comment: You meant 'quartile'.

Comment: @MickyboYakari qua**n**tile, qua**r**tile is a kind of quantile.

Comment: I am aware of that. What do you think is a 'second quantile'? Surely, you meant 'the second quartile'. :)

Comment: @MickyboYakari oh, here, right. Thanks for pointing that!

Comment: You are welcome.